# Create .exe from .jar with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, launch4j

I want to use gradle to create from my code .jar, and then from .jar create .exe. I have a simple Java code

```
package project;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

and a build.gradle file.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
    id 'edu.sc.seis.launch4j'
}

jar.enabled = false

group 'project'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'


java {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
}

repositories {
}

dependencies {
}

shadowJar {
    archiveBaseName.set('toJarToExeFat')
    archiveVersion.set('0.1')
    archiveClassifier.set('')
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'project.main'
    }
}

tasks.shadowJar.dependsOn tasks.build

createExe {
    outfile = 'test.exe'
    mainClassName = 'project.main'
    jar = "C:/work/java/toJarToExe/build/libs/toJarToExeFat-0.1.jar"
}

tasks.createExe.dependsOn tasks.shadowJar
```

It works, but when I run .exe, I get "This application requires Java Runtime Environment 1.8.0".

I was expecting to receive .exe as if I wrote this program in C

Comment: I solved the problem by updating the plugin to the latest version. Although you cannot specify jar path in it. I also added header Type = 'console' to launch4j{}

Answer (score 0):

According the error message I would say JRE not installed on Machine where you run your "exe". I had the same problem with last version (java 21), which was installed only "inside" IntellijIDEA and it has been resolved as soon as I intalled it on my system.